# accidentally disabled network adapter on virtual machine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I accidentally disabled the network adapter on Windows virtual machine on compute engine. I tried delete-access-config and add-access-config through gcloud utility and that did not seem to make any difference. Any suggestions on how to enable the network adapter back so I can RDP back into VM or am I going to have to re-build the VM?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

To those having this issue in 2017. I was just having same problem and spent a day trying to figure out a solution. I ended up successfully enabling network adapter using serial port connection. Here are the steps:

1) Open Google Compute VM instance from the console and click "Edit"

2) Scroll down to "Serial Port" and enable it. Save...

3) Select drop down next to "Connect to serial port" and chose "Port 2"

4) New window will open with serial command prompt. Run "cmd" command in it

5) Once executed switch to cmd channel by pressing ESC+Tab

6) Authenticate with user credentials that has admin rights on your instance

7) Now you have access to your instance command prompt. To enable your network interface run the following commands:

- netsh interface show interface (this will show you all network adapter names, remember the name of the one you need to enable)
- netsh interface set interface "network_adapter_name" admin=enable
  (e.g netsh interface set interface "MyEthernet" admin=enable)

8) Show everyone around how happy you are to figure this one out.

Comment: Woooowww. Thanks a lot Man. Just had a step or two different.

Edit the instance and enable serial port on top. Don't have to choose anything from the dropdown.
Then save changes, the page will go back. Here, simply click Connect to Serial Console and rest is same as your steps from 4 to 8 :)

Thanks a lot Stan.

Answer (score 0):

At present, there's no way to enable a disabled network interface on a Windows GCE VM, therefore rendering RDP unusable. Recreating the VM anew seems like the only option.

In order not to lose data from your disabled instance, make sure "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted" is unchecked in the Developers Console configuration for this VM prior to deleting the instance. You can then attach the left-behind disk to your new instance, in order to retrieve data. Afterwards you may keep or delete the additional disk.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to use a startup script with something like `netsh interface set interface name="NAME OF INTERFACE" admin=enabled` to do the trick too?

Comment: The problem with restating a vm with the network interface disabled, in order for the startup script to be triggered, is that the boot stalls since the vm can't connect to the metaserver. The system therefore can not be given the startup script commands. In fact, I believe it hangs before reaching that stage of execution. Data res-q remains the best option in such a case.

Comment: Ui true, that might be a problem